# Use mod_rewrite & mod_jk to access different workers

Tags: mod-rewrite, mod-jk

I want to achieve the following:

There is one DMZ-proxy over which we want to access multiple application-servers, represented by mod_jk workers.

The web-context needs to be the same on all application servers, since they run the same application. We just want to access different servers via a additional "folder" within the URL.

e.g.:

some-fancy-url.com/**hh1**/some/application/

--> `JKMount /some/application/* worker-handheld1`

some-fancy-url.com/**it1**/some/application/

--> `JKMount /some/application/* worker-localhost`

So depending on that keyword between URI and context we want to forward the request to different workers; the application server needs to receive the request without this keyword though.

How can we achieve this? mod_rewrite I suppose?

Comment: They can't have the exact same context as you then can't tell them apart. So `JKMount /hh1/some/application/* worker-handheld1` and  `JKMount /it1/some/application/* worker-localhost`

Comment: this would mean changing the JBoss application for each environment. The idea was that mod_rewrite tells them apart and then "routes" the request to the correct worker. Somehow. This is impossible, you say? What about different virtual hosts?

Comment: Multiple virtual hosts won't make a difference because you would just end up with the same rewrites and jkmounts in both virtual hosts.   mod_rewrite could certainly tell you the difference between it1 and hh1 but then would forward to /some/application/* and wouldn't be able to tell them apart as noted above.